# how to get width of a dynamic element when it render on page in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to how to get width of a dynamic element when it render on page in jquery.

I have tried the below code but did not work.

```
$('body').on('load', 'button.btnSubmit', function () {
    var width = jQuery('button.btnSubmit').width();
    alert(width);
});
```

Comment: Elements don't raise `load()` events. If you want to get the width of the element when it's added to the DOM you need to get it manually in the appending code, or use a `MutationObserver` on the DOM

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please give example ? I am also interested in same question

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).ready()` instead?

Comment: thanks @Rory, could you pls provide me a sample for this ?

Comment: Explain more about the "dynamic" part of that element, do you create it on demand like as rendering ajax response, or you render it using js when the page loads?

Comment: i have converted a drop down to a multiselect dropdown using jquery plugin

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var btn_width = $("button.btnSubmit").width();
  alert(btn_width);
})
```

Comment: It returns null in output

Answer (score 0):

You said a dynamic element, I guess you create it and append it using jquery append().

Try to put the .width() in the same method that creates the element.

```
function createElement(){
   var newElement = $("body").append($.parseHTML("<div>blah</div>"));
   return newElement.width()
}
```